# faster method for making movie in gnuplot

Tags: animation, video, gnuplot, simulation, mp4

I think we were using `gnuplot` for decades. But still there is no good way to get a good video output from `gnuplot`, am I right? What I did is made around 30,000 images (I had to make it with good quality too, to get video clarity), then used `ffmpeg` to make the video:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 10.0 -i capture.%d.png -qscale 1 filename.mp4
```

But some time I get stuck in between or it takes too long time. We may always need a video output with high quality and low file size, why no one is attempting to do anything, or is there any other method to make video out put from `gnuplot`? I am really struggling to make high quality videos with `gnuplot`.

Comment: I appologise for the frst comment  " we were using gnuplot for decades. But still there is no good way to get a good video output from gnuplot", this is really aesome!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pipe the output of `gnuplot` directly to `ffmpeg` without storing the images on the hard drive. For that you need to tell `ffmpeg` what format and resolution it has to expect from the pipe, since it can not guess it alone from the extension etc. now. Here is an example:

```
gnuplot animation.plt | ffmpeg -f png_pipe -s:v 800x600 -i pipe: out.mp4
```

I used the code from [here](http://www.gnuplotting.org/animation-gif/) with some minor modifications.

**animation.plt**

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
#
# Creating an animation gif of the Bessel function
# NOTE: this files creates multiple png images, the gif file is then created
# using GIMP
#
# AUTHOR: Hagen Wierstorf

reset
set terminal pngcairo size 800,600 enhanced font 'Verdana,10'

# color definitions
set palette rgb 3,9,9

unset key; unset colorbox; unset border; unset tics
set lmargin at screen 0.03
set bmargin at screen 0
set rmargin at screen 0.97
set tmargin at screen 1

set parametric
# Bessel function, which is moving in time
bessel(x,t) = besj0(x) * cos(2*pi*t)
# calculate the zeros for the bessel function (see Watson, "A Treatise on the
# Theory of Bessel Functions", 1966, page 505)
n = 6 # number of zeros
k = (n*pi-1.0/4*pi)
u_0 = k + 1/(8*k) - 31/(384*k)**3 + 3779/(15360*k)**5
set urange [0:u_0]
set vrange[0:1.5*pi]
set cbrange [-1:1]
set zrange[-1:1]

set isosamples 200,100
set pm3d depthorder
set view 40,200

# initializing values for the loop and start the loop
t = 0
end_time = 1
#system('mkdir -p animation')
load 'bessel.plt'
```

**bessel.plt**

```
# bessel loop
t = t + 0.02
#outfile = sprintf('animation/bessel%03.0f.png',50*t)
#set output outfile
splot u*sin(v),u*cos(v),bessel(u,t) w pm3d ls 1
if(t<end_time) reread;
```

Gives you a video which looks like this. (This is downscaled and transcoded gif just for demo purposes)
[image: compressed gif]

You can also play around with ffmpeg encoder parameters. here only default video encoder config is used.

Comment: I got two errors.. !!!  , [png @ 0x206e660] Invalid PNG signature 0xD494844520000.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input,

Comment: could you please explain the difference in ffmpeg commands that you used and the one I pasted. or some link to understand what each terms stands for like what's -image2, png-pipe etc..

Comment: @fahd ok first of all did you get it to work with the code I posted? I assume the problem appears when you use your gnuplot script? The difference between image2 and png_pipe is that the first reads from the list of image files while the second awaits piped png sequence. Maybe in your case image2pipe will work.

Comment: Once I made a gif with 3000*3000 pixel size, and the file is about 300 MB. But I was unable to do anything with that file. Even if I open the containing folder, my Pc gets stuck.. However I need that much or more resolution since my particles are rectangular in shape. thats why I moved to ffmpeg so that atleast I could open the files just as a movie. But is there any way I can make gif (Mp4 too) files with high resolution but lighter in size ?, Can I contact you @incBrain ?

Comment: yeah.. that code gave me video output. But somewhere they showed that errors

Comment: Are there anymore options as png_pipe,image2,image2pipe, etc

Comment: okay,thanks I saw the whole docucumentation in it's website. So is there any way to produce lighter gif's or MP4's?

Comment: gif uses either no compression at all or lossless compression (which can not be that efficient in terms of file size, since its lossless) in case of mp4 (its a container format) you can specify a codec (e.g. h.264 or h.265) of your video and configuration of the encoder yourself. For example [h.254 encoding guidelines](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

Comment: Thanks for that too, I think it might help, Now one more last thing. I am doing simulations on ballistic particles moving in a lattice,collides and evolves I was plotting during the time of program running itself, means I did't make files to plot from instead during the run each time I know whichever sites are occupied, and set 'obj rect' there and plot something(plot 0) using pipe from directy from C(using popen,etc). Then how can I implement this '|' separated command to bring ffmpeg into play?

Comment: @fahd you can use ffmpeg libraries from your code. Read more about it [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Using%20libav*)

Comment: what is the default frames per second in this case, I mean what will be that in the case I use the command you gave ?

Comment: @fahd what about setting the framerate yourself? Im pretty sure you can figure it out ;) I don't have every default value for each parameter stored in my head